# Accuracy of the skip-gramm(word2vec) model for the words similarity using brown dataset(NLTK)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I want to create similarity matrix based on the brown dataset from the NLTK library. The problem is that loss

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights = softmax_weight, biases = softmax_bias, inputs = embed,
                  labels = y, num_sampled = num_sampled, num_classes = num_words))
```

decreases from 4.2 to 2.0 and then it starts to go up and down.
The question is: how can I improve accuracy of my model?

Here is my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding,Layer
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from numpy.random import choice
import random
from itertools import repeat
import tensorflow as tf
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import brown
import string
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('stopwords')


#Dataset loading and preparation:
dataset = brown.sents()

punct = list(string.punctuation)
punct.append("``")
punct.append("''")
punct.append("--")
stops = set(stopwords.words("english")) 

dataset = [[word.lower() for word in sentence if word not in punct and word.lower() not in stops] for sentence in dataset] 


#tokenization
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dataset)

word2index = tokenizer.word_index
index_word = tokenizer.index_word

total_words = 5000

data_prep = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dataset) 
data_prep = [sentence for sentence in data_prep if len(sentence) >2] 

#word2vec
def word2vec_preparation(data,window_size,num_skips):
    grams = []
    context = []
    target = []

    assert window_size >= 1,'windows_size argument is <1!'
    assert num_skips >= 1,'num_skips argument <1!'
    for sentence in data:
        if len(sentence) - window_size > 1:
            #print(sentence)

            for i in range(len(sentence)):
                if i - window_size < 0:
                    gram = sentence[i+1:i+window_size + 1]
                    check = num_skips - len(set(gram))
                    #print(gram)
                    grams.append(gram)
                    if check > 0:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), len(set(gram))))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], len(set(gram))))
                    else:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), num_skips))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], num_skips))

                elif i + window_size > len(sentence) -1:
                    gram = sentence[i-window_size:i]
                    check = num_skips - len(set(gram))
                    #print(gram)
                    grams.append(gram)
                    if check > 0:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), len(set(gram))))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], len(set(gram))))
                    else:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), num_skips))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], num_skips))

                else:
                    gram = sentence[i-window_size:i] + sentence[i+1:i+window_size + 1]
                    check = num_skips - len(set(gram))
                    #print(gram)
                    grams.append(gram)
                    if check > 0:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), len(set(gram))))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], len(set(gram))))
                    else:
                        context.extend(random.sample(set(gram), num_skips))
                        target.extend(repeat(sentence[i], num_skips))

        #print('----------------------')

    return grams, context, target

grams,context,target = word2vec_preparation(data_prep,window_size = 2,num_skips = 3)

target = np.array(target,dtype= np.int64)
context = np.array(context,dtype= np.int64)


context = context.reshape(len(context),1)
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((target, context))
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

#Parameters:
num_words = 5000
embed_size = 300
num_sampled = 64
initializer_softmax = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
#Variables:
embeddings_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([num_words,embed_size],-1.0,1.0))
softmax_weight = tf.Variable(initializer_softmax([num_words,embed_size]))
softmax_bias = tf.Variable(initializer_softmax([num_words]))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

@tf.function
def training(X,y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_weight,X)#embeddings_weight are parameters and X is a collection of indecies for looking up in the embedding table
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights = softmax_weight, biases = softmax_bias, inputs = embed,
                  labels = y, num_sampled = num_sampled, num_classes = num_words))
  variables = [embeddings_weight,softmax_weight,softmax_bias]  
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss,variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,variables))
  return loss
  #tf.print('Loss:',loss)



EPOCHS = 100

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for step, (X,y) in enumerate(dataset_train):
    loss = training(X,y)
  tf.print('Epoch:',epoch + 1, 'loss:',loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reported loss isn't the gold-standard of a model's usefulness – actual testing of the resulting word-vectors against real uses is.

And, having the loss plateau (then jitter up-and-down) is the natural and expected behavior of the this sort of optimization. (The model will never be perfect at predicting the training data, unless it's massively oversized for the data – in which case it will be 'overfit' on the training data & likely underperform at real tasks.) You want loss to each as low as it can, given a certain algorithm & model parameters – not to 0.0.

There might be other errors in your code, which I haven't reviewed. I'd suggest using an off-the-shelf, debugged `Word2Vec` implementation – either directly, or, if it's really important (perhaps for learning purposes) to use your own implementation, as a benchmark against which to judge if your code is working.